# Can't install the "feedback hub" using microsoft store

Tags: windows-store-app, microsoft

I am trying to install the "feedback hub" app in windows 10 using microsoft store.
Store seems to not be very responsive and hand out clues on what is going wrong.

The install button (swedish language) looks like this before pressed:

[image]

When it is pressed, it becomes a bit smaller:

[image]

When you do not press it any longer the size is restored:

[image]

Any ideas about how to get knowledge about what's failing are welcome.

Comment: I did not overtly install Feedback but it exists on 4 real machines and 1 virtual machine. Open search and type feedback. It comes up that way for me.

Comment: Ah, on windows 11 that would be true, and I have that on one machine!